# How to write UD Pipe tagger output to file?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I have been using [UD Pipe](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/udpipe) to train and tag data in the Hindi Language.

I run the tagger using

> udpipe --tag model.output hi-ud-test.conllu

which works perfectly fine and displays the output in command line. How do I write this output in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the command

> udpipe --tag model.output hi-ud-test.conllu > output.txt

This will write your output in a txt file called "output" instead of displaying in the terminal